Eliminate the parameters in a symmetric linear-algebra condition
Let positive vectors $x_1,x_2,x_3,p_1,p_2,p_3\in\mathbb R^3_+$.
Consider the following condition on the six points $x'$s and $p'$s.
Condition:

For all $y_1,y_2,y_3$ satisfying the following five equations:
$p_1\cdot y_1=p_1\cdot y_2=p_1 \cdot x_1 \ \ $ (1),
$p_2\cdot y_2=p_2\cdot y_3=p_2 \cdot x_2\ \ $ (2),
$p_3\cdot y_3=p_3\cdot y_1=p_3 \cdot x_3\ \ $ (3),
$|y_1-x_1|\leq |y_2-x_1|\ \ $ (4),
$|y_2-x_2|\leq |y_3-x_2|\ \ $ (5).
We must have:
$|y_1-x_3|\leq |y_3-x_3|$.

Question: Is it possible to use vector-algebra or matrix algebra to reduce and simplify this six-line condition such that all $y$ are eliminated, leaving only vectors $x$ and $p$?
My attempt: First I observe that the "condition" is only about $x$ and $p$; the $y$ are only auxiliary parameters.
For example, observe that $p_1y_1=p_1x_1$ and $p_3y_1=p_3x_3$. Note that $p_1,x_1$ defines a plane and $p_3,x_3$ defines another plane. Intuitively, $y_1$ is just an intersection of that plane.
We could possibly combine the first three equations (1)(2)(3) into one single matrix equation:
$$[p_1,p_2,p_3]^T[y_1,y_2,y_3]=\begin{bmatrix}
p_1\cdot x_1 & p_1\cdot x_1 & p_1\cdot y_3\\
p_2\cdot y_1 & p_2\cdot x_2 & p_2\cdot x_2 \\
p_3\cdot x_3 & p_3\cdot y_2 &p_3\cdot x_3
\end{bmatrix}$$
And then do the same for (4)(5).
